# Visual Basic - How to search the whole system for a filename or string?

Tags: vb.net

I am wondering how to search the entire computer for a filename or a string in the file, maybe a text file or what not. Now before you get all mad about me not putting work into this, I did google it while a lot of name changes and stuff. I did find this one article on google that related to it, and I found some good code for use for examples, but It just wasn't working. So again, I want to search the ENTIRE system for a specific file name or string in the file. Thank you regards

```
On Error Resume Next
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
            My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, TextBox1.Text)

            ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
        Next
```

By the way, I see that My.Computer.Filesystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, how could I get that to search the whole system, if you're going off of this code.

Comment: I suggest using everything.exe it has a good api and you can search for a specific string in the whole system

Comment: Are you talking about the API for the actual program? I found the program and downloaded it, is the API the program?

Comment: `how could I get that to search the whole system` [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have you tried such a simple thing as searching in `C:\ ` instead of `MyDocuments`??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a function that traverses through all subdirectories and then all further subdirectories and returns a List(Of String), which is often used for file paths.

I recommend to have a look at:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/recursive-file-directory-vbnet

If you don't need to search from your own application you may want to use a free File Searching Utility like [FileLocator Lite](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite) as a replacement for Windows search.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know this website existed. I'll keep looking into this function.